# Use an if-statement to ensure that an element is not present

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, python

I would like to use a if statement to ensure that an element is not present without rising a [`NoSuchElementException`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException).

So for example:

```
if(driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath")):
   print " This element shouldn't be there."
else: 
   print "It's all good, no element there."
```

How can I set my If statement to perform what I'm looking for?
Is there any Selenium command for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
if(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("xpath")) != 0):
    print "this element should not be here"
else:
    print "It is all good, no element there"
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Below snippet is working well form me

```
if(!driver.findElements(By.name("cancel")).isEmpty()) {
  System.out.println("Element present");

}
else{
  System.out.println("Element is NOT present");
}
```